# How to set Concurrency::event object only if it is not in signaled state now?

Tags: c++, concurrency

In my code some concurrency work task should start to work only if special event is not in signaled state. 
Code sample:

```
tasks.run([&](){
   if (event.wait(0)!=0)
   {
      event.set();

      // work code ...
   }
})
```

Such task may have many instances and only one should to work. But wait() and set() are different methods and code is not atomic. So, may be situation when two or more instances of task begin to work.
How I can test event for signaled state and lock it only if it is non-signaled, and do it in atomic manner ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you may use [mutex::try_lock](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex/try_lock)

the code should look like this:

```
tasks.run([&](){
   if (event.wait(0)!=0 && mutex.try_lock()) {
      event.set();
      mutex.unlock();
      // work code ...
   }
})
```

Don't forget to make sure that event.set() doesn't throw an exception, otherwise extra efforts are needed to make this code exception-safe.

May be you should wrap the entire into while (true) to catch 'false-positive' cases, smth like that:

```
tasks.run([&](){
   while(true) {
      if (event.wait(0)!=0 && mutex.try_lock()) {
         event.set();
         mutex.unlock();
         // work code ...
         break;
      }
   }
});
```

Thus tasks failed to acquire the lock would return to the wait state.

Comment: Better code: `tasks.run([&](){
   if (mutex.try_lock() && event.wait(0)!=0) {
      event.set();
      mutex.unlock();
      // work code ...
   }
})`

Comment: Well, that's not true, at least for some cases. Consider the following situation: one thread acquires lock and then waits for the even. Another thread tries to acquire a lock, immediately fails and then goes to the loop again and again. It's a good method to overload your CPU w/o any actual work being done :)

Comment: So you either need to use `lock` instead of `try_lock` and thus block until the lock acquisition, or need to reverse the order of the checks

Comment: Yes, you are right, I should use lock() method. Look at my version of issue solution.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

Safe set event class:

```
namespace Concurrency {

class event_safe : public event
{
public:

    inline bool try_set()
    {
        critical_section::scoped_lock locker(m_lock);

        bool bRes = (wait(0)==Concurrency::COOPERATIVE_WAIT_TIMEOUT);
        if (bRes)
            set();

        return bRes;
    }

protected:
    critical_section m_lock;
};

}
```

Work code:

```
tasks.run([&](){
   if (event.try_set()) {
      // work code ...
   }
})
```

Comment: Well, newer C++ (C++11) has portable [std::mutex](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex), [std::unique_lock](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/unique_lock) and [std::lock_guard](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard) things.

Comment: Also you may consider putting your events into a queue if the number of tasks is less then a number of events or if events may arrive simultaneously. Look eg at [boost::lockfree::queue](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0b1/doc/html/boost/lockfree/queue.html)

Comment: STL sync methods (std::mutex, std::unique_lock and std::lock_guard) are cool, but my project use C++ ConcurrencyRT and I don't want to merge this two approaches. Especially that ConcurrencyRT sync classes affect on context switch rules.